# How to remove overflow: auto property?

Tags: css

I have set overflow property as auto for a div. But when I click on a button, I want the div should get expanded and want the overflow property to be removed.

```
#viewNotings{
  width: 310px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I want to remove this overflow property in a different page.

Comment: That's not related to JavaScript / JSP .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want a behavior when clicking, state it in the "onclick" field of the element (div, span, img, a...).

if you want this behavior to modify a style property, set this.style.PROPERTY accordingly.

->

```
<div onclick="this.style.overflow='visible';">
```

Comment: If you provided an explanation perhaps your answer would be worth voting it up ;-]

Comment: Getting an error- 'Could not get the Overflow parameter, Invalid argument'

Comment: sorry: "none" is not valid. use one of visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;

Comment: I want to remove the overflow property by writting the code in a js file which is included in the jsp where I had set the css properties of viewNotings.

Comment: The correct code isdocument.getElementById("viewNotings").style.cssText="overflow-x:visible;";

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is

```
document.getElementById("viewNotings").style.cssText="overflow-x:visible;";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText

> cssText returns or sets the text of the element's inline style declaration only.

Comment: Refers to the questioners exact want to re-set an `overflow-x` property (as opposed to an `overflow` property.)

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is very simple set empty value to the overflow property that is enough.

```
<div onclick="this.style.overflow=' ';">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Register a jquery click event for div
- On click, remove overflow and set width to 100%

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#viewNotings").click(function () {
    $("#viewNotings").css("overflow", "none");
    $("#viewNotings").css("width", "100%");
  });
 });
```

```css
#viewNotings{
  width: 310px;
  background: gray;
  height: 30px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="viewNotings"></div>
</body>
```